# Defined variable becomes undefined for some reason

Tags: javascript

I have this code here:

```
if (message.channel.id === "624637964827492352") {
  if (message.content === '/start'){
    var maf = 1
    console.log('Game Started')
    console.log(maf)
  }
  if (message.content === '/in'){
    console.log(maf)
  }
}
```

If you type `/start` it makes the variable `maf = 1`, then logs the variable value as 1 and the string `'Game Started'`. When I type `/in`, it logs `maf` as `undefined`. Why is it not staying as `1`? I'm very confused as to why the variable is resetting! I'm also quite new to Discord coding and Javascript in general.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That code is probably in a function, so every time the function is called there's a completely new variable.

Comment: you've defined `maf` within the context of `if (message.content === '/start')` so using it in the separate context of `if (message.content === '/in')` gives you `undefined` because it is literally not defined there.

Answer (score 1):

If this code is inside a function (and probably it is), the variables defined in the function will be discarded when the function exits because of the variable's scope.

To store a value permanently, define it outside that function:

```js
var a; //Declare variable outside
function someFunction(){
  if (message.channel.id === "624637964827492352") {
    if (message.content === '/start'){
      maf = 1
      console.log('Game Started')
      console.log(maf)
    }
    if (message.content === '/in'){
      console.log(maf)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The code is not in a function. That is all the code I have for my Discord bot.

Comment: @PhilipMarchand Then please post your full code, otherwise the problem can't be detected...